# Netbeans PHP watch static variables

Tags: php, netbeans, static-variables

How to do that? I tried adding watch like ClassName::$VarName, it doesn't seem to work. The variable is public.
I need to watch public static class variable from outside of class scope.

```
class SomeClass {
    public static $Var;
}
SomeClass::$Var = 100;

function SomeFunc() {
// i need to watch here for the value of SomeClass::$Var;
}
```

*NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)*

*Xdebug   2.7.2* 

*PHP 7.3*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View static variable content in Netbeans PHP debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935684/view-static-variable-content-in-netbeans-php-debugger)

Comment: it seems that i can only access static class wars inside of class scope. That's not what i am looking for.

Comment: OK. I have retracted my close vote.